# Finding min() and max() of Python dictionary key-value pair complexes

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a  large tab-delimited text file list like:

> A B   543 756 Dan
>
> A B   321 420 Dan
>
> A B   475 894 Dan
>
> A B   543 756 Sarah
>
> A B   321 420 Sarah
>
> A B   475 894 Sarah

For each name (every name is unique), I want to subtract 20 from the min value of the whole complex (e.g., for Dan, the min would be 321 from Dan's six numbers) and add 10 to the max value of the whole complex (e.g, for Sarah, the max would be 894 from Sarah's six numbers).

So I am looking to write some code that captures the min and max values for each name, does a bit of arithmetic on them, and then returns an outfile identical to the MWE here (except with the changes included).
So far I have tried this:

```
file = open('people.txt', 'r+')
for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in file ):

mydict = {}
k = columns[5]
v = columns[2:3]
mydict[k] = v

d = mydict
```

I have read in the file and then tried to create a key value pair so that for each key (name, in this case), it would return the minimum value (number, in this case), but I am having trouble since there are duplicate keys (3 Dan's, 3 Sarah's, in this case).

I have also tried:

```
for name, number in d.items():
    print '{0} corresponds to {1}'.format(name, number)
```

And:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print k, 'corresponds to', v
```

To begin to attack this problem. I am not sure however that I can use a dictionary of key value pairs, since I have two columns (columns 3 and 4 from the list) both of which I need to include as one dictionary.  I tried creating two dictionaries and then merging them together, but .update() updates the dictionary since there are duplicate keys.

Could anyone please help create an outfile that is identical to this infile but has the requisite arithmetic changes to each min and max value for each specific name?

Note: As pointed out by @dawg, make sure there is no blank line at the end of your file.  Otherwise, the following error will pop up during compilation of your code: IndexError: “IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Your input has multiple lines for `Dan` - the min and max values are in separate lines;  Will the output have a single *line* for `Dan` or multiple *lines*?

Comment: just modify the file as you read it to make the modifications

Comment: @Drewdin based on the problem description, finding the value for any name requires reading in the whole list first, since the input has multiple entries per name. In addition, it sounds like the output needs to have the same lines in the same order, with the minimum value and maximum value for each person changed on their respective lines.

Comment: To the OP: Can you assume that each person's lines will always be contiguous in the file, or will they sometimes be interleaved? Either way, the trick is realizing that dictionaries can store ``lists`` as their values, and ``lists`` can store other ``lists``/``tuples``. If the lines are not contiguous, you'll need to store row metadata as well so you can put things back in the correct order. You should also look into the [``csv``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, and the [``OrderedDict``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to find the min value of the two columns associated with the names, just use `min()` and maintain a running min value:

```
import csv
import sys

def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s    

data={}
with open(fn, 'rb') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        key=row[-1]
        data.setdefault(key, sys.maxint)
        li=[conv(row[2]), conv(row[3])]
        data[key]=min(min(li), data[key])

>>> data
{'Sarah': 321, 'Dan': 321}
```

If you want all the rows as sub lists, you can do:

```
data={}
with open(fn, 'rb') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        key=row[-1]
        data.setdefault(key, []).append([conv(row[2]), conv(row[3])])

>>> data
{'Sarah': [[543, 756], [321, 420], [475, 894]], 'Dan': [[543, 756], [321, 420], [475, 894]]}
```

Then you can get the sub list value with the min value in it by using `min` with itself as the key:

```
>>> for k, li in data.items():
...     print k, min(li, key=min)
...
Sarah [321, 420]
Dan [321, 420]
```

It now becomes easy to find the row on interest, add or subtract as desired, and write it out in the same format:

```
def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s    

data={}
with open(fn_in, 'rb') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        key=row[-1]
        data.setdefault(key, []).append([conv(row[2]), conv(row[3])])

maxes={}
mins={}
for k, li in data.items():
    maxes[k]=max(li, key=max)
    mins[k]=min(li, key=min)

with open(fn_out, 'wb') as fout, open(fn_in, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    writer=csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        key=row[-1]
        tr=[conv(row[2]), conv(row[3])]
        if tr==maxes[k]:
            tgt=max(tr)
            row[2:4]=[e+10 if e==tgt else e for e in tr]
        if tr==mins[k]:    
            tgt=min(tr)
            row[2:4]=[e-20 if e==tgt else e for e in tr]

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Produces the file:

```
A   B   543 756 Dan
A   B   301 420 Dan
A   B   475 904 Dan
A   B   543 756 Sarah
A   B   301 420 Sarah
A   B   475 904 Sarah
```

---

Try:

```
# first read the file to determine the min/max
data={'max':{}, 'min':{}}
with open(fn_in, 'rb') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        key=row[-1]
        data['max'].setdefault(key, -sys.maxint-1)
        data['min'].setdefault(key, sys.maxint)
        li=[conv(row[2]), conv(row[3])]
        data['max'][key]=max([max(li), data['max'][key]])
        data['min'][key]=min(min(li), data['min'][key])

# now change the values by name:
with open(fn_out, 'wb') as fout, open(fn_in, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    writer=csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        key=row[-1]
        tr=[conv(row[2]), conv(row[3])]
        if data['max'][key] in tr:
            tgt=max(tr)
            row[2:4]=[e+10 if e==tgt else e for e in tr]
            tr=row[2:4]
        if data['min'][key] in tr:    
            tgt=min(tr)
            row[2:4]=[e-20 if e==tgt else e for e in tr]

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Starting with:

```
A   B   543 756 Dan
A   B   321 420 Dan
A   B   475 894 Dan
A   B   543 756 Sarah
A   B   321 420 Sarah
A   B   475 894 Sarah
A   B   345 477 Mike
```

Produces:

```
A   B   543 756 Dan
A   B   301 420 Dan
A   B   475 904 Dan
A   B   543 756 Sarah
A   B   301 420 Sarah
A   B   475 904 Sarah
A   B   325 487 Mike
```

Comment: Since we are using relative indexing from the end, you could only get `IndexError` with `row[-1]` if there are no elements in row. That is probably a blank line in your file. Does you file have empty lines in it?

Comment: I am having similar issues with your code as with @wwii's code: if I have a single entry of a name, the min-20 works fine, but the max+10 doesn't work. For example, just add a single  `A   B   345   477   Mike` to the input file to see this... the output will be `A   B   325   477   Mike`

Comment: @XYZ927: If you want to handle the case where a name has a single list, you will need to add a `if` clause to handle that. You will also have a special case with `A   B   300   300   Mike` Which is the min? Which is the max? What about if you have repeated min and max values on multiple lines? Replace them all or only the first instance? Only you can define these cases -- I cannot.

Comment: actually that is not a problem, all the numbers will be unique with no repeats (across multiple lines or otherwise).  Could you please add your if clause to your script to modify it for this simple case?  To @wwii, could you please show in your script how to replicate a similar scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with a dictionary for your container:

Use `collections.defaultdict`, each item value will contain every line for each unique name

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b, low, hi, name = line.strip().split()
        d[name].append([a, b, low, hi, name])
```

Assuming the min values will always be in column 2 and the max values in columns 3, sort on column two and the min will be in the first row; sort on column 3 and the max will be in the last row.

```
first_row = operator.itemgetter(0)
last_row = operator.itemgetter(-1)
column2 = operator.itemgetter(2)
column3 = operator.itemgetter(3)

for name, data in d.items():
    data.sort(key = column2)
    data[0][2] = str(int(column2(first_row(data))) - 20)

    data.sort(key = column3)
    data[-1][3] = str(int(column3(last_row(data))) + 10)
```

I couldn't figure out how to accomplish the assignment using ```operator.itemgetter`` - if anyone knows how, please edit.

Then finally, to write the result:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('\n'.join(' '.join(line) for data in d.itervalues() for line in data))
```

The result should be `identical to this infile but has the requisite arithmetic changes`

Comment: The min or the max could be in either column.  As Aruisdante correctly notes: "it sounds like the output needs to have the same lines in the same order, with the minimum value and maximum value for each person changed on their respective lines."  So basically the output should be completely identical to the input, just the min value for each name should have 20 subtracted from it, and the max value for each name should have 10 added to it.  The output list should look identical though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer wwii, very interesting use of collections.defaultdict(list).

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was insufficient. I'm posting a second, completely rethought answer.

***Create a Line object with comparison methods:***

```
import operator
numbers = operator.itemgetter(2,3)
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        a = line.split()
        self.min = min(map(int, numbers(a)))
        self.max = max(map(int, numbers(a)))
        self.name = a[-1]
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.min < other.min
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.max > other.max
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return (self.min == other.min) and (self.max == other.max)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.line
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Line('{}')".format(self.line)
```

***Read the file and create a set of names***

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
data_lines = map(Line, data.split('\n'))
names = {line.name for line in data_lines}
```

***Make a list of Lines for each name, then find the lines with the max and min values and replace those lines in the original data with modified lines***

```
for name in names:
    # make a list of Lines for each name (filter for name),
    person_data = [line for line in data_lines if line.name == name]
    # find the lines with the max and min values
    max_line = max(person_data)
    min_line = min(person_data)

    # replace those lines in the original data with modified lines
    if max_line is min_line:
        new_line = str(max_line).replace(str(max_line.max), str(max_line.max + 10))
        new_line = new_line.replace(str(min_line.min), str(min_line.min - 20))
        data = data.replace(str(max_line), new_line)
    else:
        new_max = str(max_line).replace(str(max_line.max), str(max_line.max + 10))
        data = data.replace(str(max_line), new_max)

        new_min = str(min_line).replace(str(min_line.min), str(min_line.min - 20))
        data = data.replace(str(min_line), new_min)
```

***Write to a new file***

```
with open('file_new.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: I very much like the class you created in this completely rethought answer, this code runs successfully.  How may I thumb up this answer as well as @dawg's answer, whose method is also very original and, at the same time, very different in its approach?

Comment: @XYZ927 did you try to *plus one* the answer?  You already accepted dawg's which is OK with me.

Comment: if I have a single entry of a name, the min-20 works fine, but the max+10 doesn't work. For example, just add a single  `A   B   345   477   Mike` to the input file to see this...  the output will be `C   D   325   477   Mike`

Comment: Correction: A and B will stay the same (C and D is a typo, it should be A and B)

Comment: Can there be more than one line with the minimum (or maximum) value in it? e.g. - ```A B 273 567 Lena``` and ```A B 273 432 Lena```

Comment: No, it's the simplest possible case, basically no repeats and all numbers are unique.

Comment: @XYZ927 See edit; quite a bit (most) changed, no more regexes - handles a single line file.

Comment: +1 for the very well organized (and concise) code and great comments. Once my reputation level gets to +15, I will be unlocked to upvote your answer.

Comment: Hi wwii!  I’ve decided to implement the code in this answer in an alpha release of a GPLv3 project that I am currently working on.  Can I get in touch with you to ask you what kind of attribution you would like (e.g., @wwii or first/last name or none at all, etc.)?  Perhaps you would even be interested in contributing to my Github page?  In any case, perhaps we should swap emails or some other contact info :-)  Talk to you soon!

Comment: @warship, no need for an attribution - shirley you aren't using this verbatim.  It's interesting, today I would have sorted ```data_lines``` and used ```itertools.groupby``` to produce groups of ```Line```'s with the same name.